# database normalization and optimization for postOffice DB

Tags: database-design

I am designing a web application for a post office.
Performance in database is critical for them.
I have designed the below structure for the post database, is there any flaw in my db structure which I didn't pay attention to ?
I couldn't post the image please someone do that for me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSEMP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that's not a database structure. Post column names, keys, constraints, and so on.

Second, performance is not critical. Data integrity is critical. Returning the wrong answer really, really fast won't help any post office.

Third, data integrity depends on keys, constraints, and so on. See "First".

Comment: I worked with a great DB2 DBA many years ago who described his job as "helping people make bigger and better mistakes, faster."  - I agree that this is not a question in its current form.

Comment: I'll post that a few days later, tnx.